SwiftUI Table with clickable cell for editing contents
I'm trying to make a three column Table in SwiftUI where entries can be edited by double clicking on the cell.
Very similar to the DNS Entry table in MacOS' System Settings:

After hours of searching I haven't found a way to do it.  The Table itself works. This is the code so far:
struct EditItem : Identifiable
{
    var id          : Int
    var original    : String
    var replacement : String
}

struct EditView : View
{
    @State var mEditList  : [EditItem] =
    [
        EditItem(id: 1, original: "bobo", replacement: "freddy"),
        EditItem(id: 2, original: "abcde", replacement: "gateway")
    ]
    @State var mSelection : Int?
    @State var mSortKey   = [KeyPathComparator(\EditItem.original)]
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack()
        {
            Text("OCR is not a perfect science and makes mistakes. Please edit the list below to correct them.")
    
            Table(mEditList, selection: $mSelection, sortOrder: $mSortKey)
            {
                TableColumn(Text("##").font(.system(size: 12)), value: \.id)
                {
                    item in
                    Text("\(item.id)").font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                .width(50)
                
                TableColumn(Text("Replace").font(.system(size: 12)), value: \.original)
                {
                    item in
                    Text(item.original).font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                
                TableColumn(Text("With...").font(.system(size: 12)), value: \.replacement)
                {
                    item in
                    Text("\(item.replacement)").font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                
            }
            .font(.title)
            .onChange(of: mSortKey)
            {
                mEditList.sort(using: mSortKey)
            }
        }
    }
}

Target platform is MacOS (not iOS).
EDIT I
The approach from @soundflix is almost there.  I've added textFieldStyle to the TextField so you can see it is editable, however, when the field is 'editing' the text jumps to the right a few pixels.

I've played around with .padding in various places but can't get the text to align with the non-editing rows.
        HStack
        {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding(.horizontal, 0)
        
            Button("Done")
            {
                isEditing = false
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            .font(.system(size: 12))
        }
        .padding(0)

Secondly, how can I highlight the entire row upon single-click?  I need to provide the "+/-" buttons like the DNS example shows...

What about your implementation doesn't meet your requirements?

If you can accept it without sorting and selection functionality, you could try it with below EditableTextView.
Double clicking the cell makes the text binding editable.
struct EditView: View {
    @State private var mEditList: [EditItem] = [
        EditItem(id: 1, original: "bobo", replacement: "freddy"),
        EditItem(id: 2, original: "abcde", replacement: "gateway")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("OCR is not a perfect science and makes mistakes. Please edit the list below to correct them.")
            
            Table($mEditList) {
                TableColumn(Text("##")) { item in
                    Text("\(item.id)")
                }
                .width(50)
                
                TableColumn("Replace") { $item in
                    EditableTextView(text: $item.original)
                }
                
                TableColumn("With...") { $item in
                    EditableTextView(text: $item.replacement)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditableTextView: View {
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if isEditing {
            HStack {
                TextField("Text", text: $text)
                Button("Done") {
                    isEditing = false
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
        } else {
            Text("\(text)")
                .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                    isEditing = true
                }
        }
    }
}


Thanks! It is almost there.  Please see the question above for additional comments/questions.

soundflix, any suggestion?
